# storcli64 not finding my MegaRAID 9750-4i

Tags: linux, raid, megaraid, storcli

Fedora-38 Workstation (32 cores, 64 threads, 128GB RAM) w/mods to make it more Server-like always available.  LSI SAS MegaRAID 9750-4i PCI controller.  Four identical 8TB SAS drives intended for RAID-10, but that's irrelevant when you can't even find the controller.

BTW, I AM running storcli64 as root...

```
root@Level10 mike# scli /c0 show all

CLI Version = 007.2310.0000.0000 Nov 02, 2022
Operating system = Linux 6.3.8-200.fc38.x86_64
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Controller 0 not found
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I ran this command as root:  'scli /c0 show all' (where scli is a symbolic link pointing to the storcli64 executable) and I received the following: 'CLI Version = 007.2310.0000.0000 Nov 02, 2022
Operating system = Linux 6.3.8-200.fc38.x86_64
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Controller 0 not found' as the response.  Is that any clearer?  Is there something I can try that would be more informative?

Answer (score 0):

The ref man says: The StorCLI tool supports the following MegaRAID products.
 The 926x product line.
 The 928x product line.
 The 924x product line.
 LSI® MegaRAID SAS iMR
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9280-8e
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260CV-8i
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9266CV-8i
 LSI MegaRAID SAS 9285-8e

Which (obviously) doesn't include the 3ware 9750-4i, so StorCLI isn't the tool needed.  Anyone know what tool can be used instead of StorCLI (FYI, the older MegaRAID management tool fails to install properly on Fedora-38).